# Generating interactive graphic algorithms

Tags: interactive, graphic

http://cs.nyu.edu/~jhan/ftirtouch/

http://multi-touchscreen.com/

At above sites, there are some multitouch sample video and images.
I'm interested in that software more than multitouch interface.
So cool!

It's not just an simple volume visualizer in WMP. The colors are spread just like water, and bubbles get separated or combined very smoothly.

Is there anyone who know these graphic processing algorithms or logics?

I even don't know what keywords to search.
Any keywords, site urls,or books are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the various publications by the authors. I bet they explain some of their methods there.

You might also want to have a look at http://processing.org/

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm used to generate the fluid visuals is an implementation of [the fluid solver design](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/reality/Research/pdf/GDC03.pdf) Jos Stam presented at the 2003 Games developer conference, which has been adapted to handle RGB densities. Memo Akten released a library for both the C++ (OpenFrameworks) and Processing languages called MSAFluid that implements Stams solver design in this manner and it is fairly simple for you to use in whatever project you want.

**Links:**

[MSA Fluid (OpenFrameworks).](https://github.com/memo/ofxMSAFluid)

[MSA Fluid (Processing).](https://github.com/memo/p5-MSAFluid)

*(Sorry, I realise this is an old thread, but I think that should answer your question..)*